# UIPageViewController - Pull in first/last page (page curl mode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

[image: Page curl with 2 pages]

Hi all,

I have 2 issues with pageviewcontroller:

1. How can I create pull in first and last page. I can't addsubview same scrollview because pagecurl don't have bounces.

   In scroll mode, I try add subview in scrollview (in this pageviewcontroller's mode), but not success, I don't understand pageviewcontroller scrollview's contentSize how to work.

   Anyway to create pull view in pageviewcontroller?
2. I wan't add separator between 2 pages, and How can I do with uiviewcontroller?

   Sorry for my bad English!

Comment: Who can help me?

Comment: I researched and resolved problem 1st. Who can help me problem 2nd?

Comment: What did you try? I have no idea about the layout you are using, but maybe add a subview on top with the separator?